# Parse Back4App iOS Swift "PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: apple" method returns task as nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, oauth, back4app

I'm trying to implement Apple Login in my iOS Swift App. I already have manual signup and Facebook login.

I have implemented apple login, and it works fine as it returns the **TOKEN** and **USER** each time.

But when I pass it in **"PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: apple"** method, this works partially, sometimes it works fine with **task returning value** and other most of the time Parse returns **task as nil**, with error "internal server error".

The error message returned by Parse is **"internal server error"**, which in Parse explains as Error without a message. I don't think there must be problem with code as it works partial times or it should've returned error message if something is wrong from my side.

Still I'm not sure am I doing this right, please let me know. Thanks in advance,

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        switch authorization.credential {

            case let credentials as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:

                let token = credentials.identityToken!
                let tokenString = String(data: token, encoding: .utf8)!
                let user = credentials.user

                print("TOKEN: \(tokenString)")
                print("USER: \(user)")

                if let _ = credentials.email, let _ = credentials.fullName {
                    track("Register New Account")
                    PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: "apple", authData: ["token":tokenString, "id": user]).continueWith { task -> Any? in
                        if ((task.error) != nil){
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.hideHUD()
                                alert("Could not login.\nPlease try again.")
                                track("Error with parse login after SIWA: \(task.error!.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                            return task
                        }
                        self.fillAppleDetails(userObject: task.result!, credentials: credentials)
                        return nil
                    }
                } else {
                    track("SignIn with Existing Account")
                    PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: "apple", authData: ["token":tokenString, "id": user]).continueWith { task -> Any? in
                        if ((task.error) != nil) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.hideHUD()
                                alert("Could not login.\nPlease try again.")
                                track("Error with parse login after SIWA: \(task.error!.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                            return task
                        }

                        let userObject = task.result

                        if userObject!.email == nil {
                            self.fillAppleDetails(userObject: task.result!, credentials: credentials)
                        } else {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                mustRefresh = true
                                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                                self.delegate?.capital()
                            }
                        }

                        return nil
                    }
                }
                break

            default: break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the standard non Bolts background method? Also can you see any errors in your Parse Server logs? Finally, you said that the task is nil, can you check to see if any PFUser is present?

Comment: The PFUser shows-up as Nil. What does that non-bolts method mean? The log error code is 1, "internal server error". In Parse it has given that error code 1 means, error with no error message.

Comment: That's my bad, I assumed there was a 'Parse result block' but it turns out there isn't. I think an internal server error would suggest there is something wrong with your server config - can you share your server config for sign in with Apple? There have also been some fixes & improvements to the implementation recently - what version of Parse Server are you running?

Comment: Which is the Parse version that you are using?
Also, have you tried the Sign In With Apple project provided in Back4app's Github?

https://github.com/back4app/SignInWithApple

I tried that one and it worked for me using the latest Parse version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error on Parse Back4App's side. It has been fixed in Parse Version 4.2.0, which is currently in Private Beta. You can mail them to get access.

Comment: For anyone else out there experiencing this issue I can confirm this has been fixed in Parse 4.2.0. After contacting Back4App support they have updated our server, however this update "should be publicly available within a few days"